# querying timestamp column in Netezza

Tags: sql, netezza

We have a table with timestamp column in Netezza. When I am selecting the count with query:

```
select count(*) from *table_name*
```

The result is X.

But when I am querying the table like

```
select count(*) from *table_name* where ts_col > t1
```

here `t1` is minimum timestamp value from the table itself result is Y.

Now Y is much lesser than X and we don't have any value of `ts_col` as `NULL`. Ideally X should equal Y. What could be the reason for such behavior?

Comment: you have a `where` clause to filter the rows. Y will obviously be less than X

Comment: You have a lot of values of "Y" in the table.

Comment: A visual inspection of the data is a good idea. Replace the count(*) with ts_col and show us the value of t1 and a couple of values of ts_col that it considers less than t1.

Comment: recently I have learned that the table has 'null' values for ts_col hence the rows are not counted when 'where' clause is used.

Comment: Since comments aren't permanent fixtures, let's put together an answer that will perhaps helps others who have the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Just to check, is this the query you are running?

```
select count(*)
from *table_name*
where ts_col > (select min(ts_col) from *table_name*);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a non-zero result from a count(*) when you would expect a zero result, I find the best thing to do is to perform a visual inspection of a sample of the result set data.

Alter your query from:

```
select count(*) from table_name where ts_col > t1
```

to

```
select ts_col, t1 from table_name where ts_col > t1 limit 10
```

Here I presume that t1 is a constant/literal.

The results of this query will point you to what you have in the table that you weren't expecting.  If ts_col is not defined as NOT NULL, then NULLs are probably your culprit, as they won't evaluate to TRUE in a boolean expression.

Otherwise, check the values you get, paying attention to type or precision displayed and compare that with you t1 value.

Answer (score 0):

Because this query

```
select count(*) from *table_name* where ts_col > t1
```

is not equal to this query.

```
select count(*) from *table_name* where ts_col >= t1
```

The value of t1 must occur precisely `X - Y` times in your table if there were no null values.

You commented on the question that there are null values in the table, so I would presume that `Y = X - (select count(1) from *table_name* where ts_col is null)`